# Is it possible not to download decoded file on server and then on client,but simply straight on client pc?

Tags: php

So I am working with Gmail API. To get attachments, I get data I must decode with base64. But it is completely irrelevant with the question. Now I allow user to download picture/file like that:

```
$attachment = $service->users_messages_attachments->get($userId, $_GET["messageId"], $_GET["attachment_id"]);
$data = $attachment->getData();
$data = strtr($data, array('-' => '+', '_' => '/'));

 $myfile = fopen("picture.jpg", "w+");;
 fwrite($myfile, base64_decode($data));
 fclose($myfile);

echo "<a href= 'picture.jpg' download= 'picture.jpg'>Download</a>";
```

It works completely fine, but I think I will use too much server space (I save every picture/file on server and then allow user to download it). Can I download It straight to client pc whitout saving picture/file on the server?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) when writing a file to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is to write the data to a file, then output an HTML page which contains a link to that file. Instead of doing that, you can simply output a link to a PHP page, which will output the data of that file.

So your link will look something like this:

```
<a href='download.php?messageId=42&attachment_id=69' download='picture.jpg'>Download</a>
```

And that `download.php` does something like this:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="picture.jpg"');

$attachment = $service->users_messages_attachments->get($userId, $_GET["messageId"], $_GET["attachment_id"]);
$data = $attachment->getData();
echo strtr($data, array('-' => '+', '_' => '/'));
```

Comment: It doesn't work completely it downloads the file but then it writes that file is not supported when I try to open it with image viewer

Comment: Open the downloaded file in a text, or better, hex editor and see what exactly you're outputting there. Probably something in addition to the raw file data.

Comment: Ok, I figured out what is the problem. the file is written with 2 blank rows at the start so If I could manage to delete that it will work. Do you have any suggestions on how could I do that?

Comment: You're simply outputting two blank lines *somewhere*. I don't know where. Maybe before your `<?php` tags.